# Создать программно bmp файл

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Смотрел решение данной проблемы на msdn и тут : C++ How to create a bitmap file

Создает файл с расширением .bmp но при этом в описании ничего нету, файл пишет что поврежден. заголовок читал, смотрел, вроде то. пытался скопировать из bmp в bmp, если полностью скопировать bmpFileHeader и bmpInfoHeader то работает. Также пробовал делать еще некоторые манипуляции, перевернуть отразить. Похоже что я что то не так делаю с заголовками

```
BITMAPFILEHEADER bmpFileHeader = { 0 };
BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpInfoHeader = { 0 };
RGBQUAD RGBcolor;
for (size_t i = 0; i < height*width; ++i)
    image[i].reserved = 0;
bmpFileHeader.bfType = 0x4d42;
bmpInfoHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmpInfoHeader.biWidth = width;
bmpInfoHeader.biHeight = height;
bmpInfoHeader.biSizeImage = (DWORD)(bmpInfoHeader.biWidth * bmpInfoHeader.biHeight);
bmpInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmpInfoHeader.biBitCount = 8;
bmpInfoHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bmpInfoHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = bmpInfoHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 2000;

bmpFileHeader.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+bmpInfoHeader.biSize + bmpInfoHeader.biSizeImage;
bmpFileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + bmpInfoHeader.biSize + sizeof(RGBQUAD);
for (size_t i = 0; i < height * width; ++i){
    fwrite(&image[i], sizeof(RGBQUAD), 1, output);
}

typedef struct RGB{
    BYTE rgbtBlue;
    BYTE rgbtGreen;
    BYTE rgbtRed;
    BYTE reserved;
};
```

Comment: Сравнить с рабочим BMP пробовали?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов пробовал. изменил biBitCount на 16 и что то пишет, но цвета искажает сильно и пишет один цвет в 3 пикселя ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bmpFileHeader.bfSize -- поле заполнено неверно, должно быть:
`bmpFileHeader.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);`

`bmpFileHeader.bfOffBits` -- здесь вы оставляете место под 256 записей палитры -- непонятно зачем, потому что очевидно палитра вам тут не нужна и вы её точто не заполняете, а сразу пишете пиксели.

Также обратите внимание, что изображение в bmp -- перевёрнутое, т.е. нижняя строка пикселов идёт первой, затем та что над ней итд.

Вообще, нужно внимательно читать описание *каждого* поля. По вашему коду видно, что многое вы упустили.
Вот описание структуры на русском: http://www.vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/Bitmaps/str_bitmapinfoheader.htm

В качестве примера работающего кода могу дать свой:
https://github.com/nzeemin/ukncbtl/blob/master/util/BitmapFile.cpp -- функция BmpFile_SaveScreenshot() в самом начале файла.

Проверьте поле `biBitCount` -- сейчас у вас оно показывает что цвет 8-битный, а заливаете вы 32-битные пиксели.

Comment: ЕМНИП, можно указать отрицательную высоту, тогда строки изображения можно будет записывать в прямом порядке.

Comment: Переделал я запись заголовка. Но он все равно пишет цвет в три пикселя,

Comment: Посмотрел Ваш код подробней. Переделал все под 8 бит. и вместо RGBTriple юзаю RGBQUAD. прочитал спек формата. в общем он просто заливает теперь мне все одним цветом... Теперь думаю копать в строну записи в файл.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, обновите ваш код в первом сообщении темы -- тогда можно будет посмотреть что сейчас не так.

Comment: @nzeemin обновил

Comment: @nzeemin пиксели RGB(8 * 8  *4) в таком случае должны быть? если заливать 8 битный цвет.

Comment: @nzeemin удалил строку с bfSize и bfoffBIts и поставил 32 бита, теперь все нормально, но в чем тогда проблема? Можете сказать?